# Getting mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in go daddy server but when i am running on localhost its running correctly

Tags: php, mysqli

my code on localhost running correctly but when i am putting code on go daddy server its keep showing this error 
what is problem i don't know here is database connection code

```
<?php

$hostname="148.72.232.172";
$username="iam4raj";
$password="*******";
$dbname="iam4raj_";
    $con=mysqli_connect($hostname,$username, $password,$dbname);
```

when i am running this code individually its running  and when i am using this `$con` variable in other code i am getting that error,why 
here is code where i am getting error

```
  <?php
                $c_query="select  * from  goverment ";
                $c_run=mysqli_query($con,$c_query);
                if(mysqli_num_rows($c_run)>0)
                {
                    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($c_run))
                    {
                        $id=$row['id'];
                        $cat=$row['category'];

                ?>
```

someone help me please .Here is error

> PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given
>   PHP Warning:  mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given

Comment: $con is null means  your database connection is wrong and it cant connect to database. please double check  db information eg. password.hostname

Comment: @scarletwitch i checked database connection is  running correctly

Comment: local and server host name is same ? can you please vardump $con?

Comment: Try localhost in hostname.

Comment: @KshitijKumar no , i cannot use becuase go daddy host correct , i talked to  them and they told me so , fyi i did check and its giving error , connection denied

Comment: Possible typo: goverment -> government

Comment: @scarletwitch no , its not same , i checked  all possible value  and only database is ruining on this code .

Comment: @KshitijKumar that is name of table and i made a spell ,mistake that time , so that same table name i am using in query

Comment: both code are in same file ?

Comment: @Sean , i did't understand there , can you help me by telling me how , please

Comment: Please add this after $con=mysqli_connect($hostname,$username, $password,$dbname); : if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

Comment: Add this after $c_run=mysqli_query($con,$c_query); : if (!$c_run)
  {
  echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
  }

Comment: host name is always localhost and use the db user name and password not the cpanel user name

Comment: while using localhost its showing access denied , and i am using db username and password not cpanel @SwadeshDash

Comment: @raj please check httpd.conf file or .htacess file. may be deny for all is their. allow it